# Why doesn't chown -R root:www-data work on my Wordpress installation?

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

Quite some time ago, I was following this tutorial which showed me how to install Wordpress on an NGINX + Ubuntu (LEMP) setup:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04

I got stuck on this portion for quite some time back then as I used `root` as the user for this instruction snippet below:

```
The group that nginx operates under is www-data. For the user portion, enter your user account name. We will demonstrate with an account called demo here:

sudo chown -R demo:www-data /var/www/html/*
```

To clarify, it didn't give me any errors or anything, but what I found out was that if I used `root:www-data` for my file ownership settings, I wouldn't be able to add / update plugins / edit code on the site. It would always prompt me for FTP / SFTP details, in which it would fail even if i entered the correct credentials due to the permissions being `drwxr-xr-x` (Owner has write permission).

So i tried this:

`sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/*`

and it worked -- I was able to write / update plugins freely as the Wordpress site admin.

However, I now have a roughly better understanding of how ownership and groups work, and I'm concerned that by doing `chown -R www-data:www-data`, I opened a security flaw on my own.

Am I doing it right? Why didn't `root:www-data` work for being able to update the site in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You are doing it right. `root:www-data` didn't work, because write permissions were given only to `owner` (root) and not `group` (www-data). If You changed folder permissions to 775 (drwxrwxr-x) it would work. More info about [permissions](http://ryanstutorials.net/linuxtutorial/permissions.php)

You should allow writing only to directories that should be written (plugins, uploads)

Comment: But given that www-data are web users, could anyone just hijack the site this way?

Answer (score 1):

7If permissions are (drwxr-xr-x) and ngnix run as 'www-data', then it can't update, modify or create new files.

```
d - means directory
rwx - Read/Write/Execute for the Owner
r-x - Read/Execute for the Group
r-x - Read/Execute for anyone else
```

you can change permissions with 'chmod':

```
sudo chmod -r 755 /var/www/html/
```